# how to fire wp_query for tag for custom post type?

Tags: wordpress

I want to fetch all article_type post that have tag "hot".  
I am using bellow query but it return all post 
 

`query_posts(array( 'posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type'=>'article_type','order' => 'ASC','tags'=>array('hot')));`

help me , thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[Do not use query_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)

Use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

As for your code, there is no [tag parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) called "tags". If you want to query multiple tags, use `'tag__in'`. If not, use `'tag'`. This example uses `'tag__in'`:

```
<?php
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'=>'article_type',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tag__in'=>array('hot')
));
if($q->have_posts()) : while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    //Post stuff.....
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget wp_reset_postdata() after the loop.

Comment: @StevenJones An excellent recommendation, provided there are multiple loops on the page. Otherwise, resetting isn't totally necessary.

Comment: I would always assume multiple loops have been run - you never know what some plugins (or even core) might be doing.

Comment: It should either, the below parameter if you're using Tag Slug 1. tag_slug__and (array) - use tag slugs.
2. tag_slug__in (array) - use tag slugs.

tag__in is use for Tag ID's

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tag= in your **wp_query** use **post_tag=** this will surely solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Query period.  Both query_posts and wp_query effect global variables.  Use get_posts instead, then you don't have to worry about your queries impacting other parts of the application/theme.

```
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'=>'article_type',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tag__in'=>array('hot')
    ));

foreach ($posts as $post) {
setup_postdata($post);

// post stuff

}

?>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to disturb the $post global you can rename your value. The caveat here is you cannot use setup_postdata() and therefore will have to GET values using the id.  For instance:

```
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'post_type'=>'article_type',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'tag__in'=>array('hot')
         ));

foreach ($posts as $pst) {

echo get_the_title($pst->ID);

}

    ?>
```

In Example 2 you needn't reset the query either.

Comment: You can use wp_reset_postdata() following looping through a WP_Query so global $wp_query is kept intact.

Comment: To your point, they ALL affect the global $post variable. But only query_posts affects the global $wp_query variable, which in turn affects a TON of other things. Using get_posts is a perfectly viable alternative, but the get_posts function itself [uses WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Parameters)

Comment: get_posts actually does not HAVE to affect the global $post variable.  If you use foreach ($someposts as $somepost) you can access it without disturbing $post, the downside is you cannot setup_postdata ANYTHING other than $post so you cannot use the_title() etc, you have to use get_the_title($somepost->ID) ). Of course you can do the same thing by defining a new wp_query, but get_post offers a faster and cleaner usage for light applications.

Comment: `get_posts` is just a wrapper function for WP_Query. It's not any faster. If anything, there's a performance hit, but we're talking a handful of clock cycles. See the source code for [get_posts](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1676) to see what I'm talking about. As far as cleanliness, that's only up to whether or not you want to maintain an Object Oriented or Procedural pattern of coding.